# Edit Shipping method

Tags: checkout

I want to calculate shipping price by other way. And it will be written in email to customer. So I want to delete 0,00US$ and keep "Shipping Line". How can I do that. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Shipping Method Page by Following Path:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml

you will find

> "0.00US$"

code in this .Phtml File. . Find and delete the Word.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can not find that word in that file

Comment: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
try here....
(OR)
Find the Class of the Span and give DISPLAY:NONE Using CSS